# Java, try-catch with Scanner

Tags: java, input, try-catch, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am creating a small algorithm and this is a part of it.

If the user enters non integer values, I want to output a message and let the user enter a number again:

```
boolean wenttocatch;

do 
{
    try 
    {
        wenttocatch = false;
        number_of_rigons = sc.nextInt(); // sc is an object of scanner class 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        wenttocatch=true;
        System.out.println("xx");
    }
} while (wenttocatch==true);
```

I am getting a never ending loop and I can't figure out why.

How can I identify if the user enters some non integer number?
If the user enters a non integer number, how can I ask the user to enter again?

**Update**
When I am printing the exception I get 'InputMismatchException', what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont have to do a try catch. This code will do the trick for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean wenttocatch = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number_of_rigons = 0;
    do{
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
        if(scan.hasNextInt()){
            number_of_rigons = scan.nextInt();
            wenttocatch = true;
        }else{
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter a valid Integer value");
        }
    }while(!wenttocatch);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear the input buffer after a valid input. You need to add this code line: 
        `scannerInput.nextLine();` after the while line in the above code.

Answer (score 6):

The `Scanner` does not advance until the item is being read. This is mentioned in [Scanner JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()). Hence, you may just read the value off using `.next()` method or check if `hasInt()` before reading `int` value.

```
boolean wenttocatch;
int number_of_rigons = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

do {
    try {
        wenttocatch = false;
        number_of_rigons = sc.nextInt(); // sc is an object of scanner class
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        sc.next();
        wenttocatch = true;
        System.out.println("xx");
    }
} while (wenttocatch == true);
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear the input buffer after a valid input. You need to add: `scannerInput.nextLine();` after the last line of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you get an exception, `wenttocatch` is set to `true` and the program will be stuck in an infinite loop. As long as you don't get the exception you'll not get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

The logic if sc.nextInt() causing the error is this

1) wenttocatch is set to false

2) sc.nextInt() throws error

3) wenttocatch is set to true

4) repeat[because wenttocatch is true]

To solve this set wentocatch=false in catch statement

```
catch (Exception e) {
               wenttocatch=false;
               System.out.println("xx");
            }
```

if you are doing more than you show here, use a counter[if your counting or a boolean if you are not], but unless you are doing more, do the first thing above

```
boolean wenttocatch;
int count = 0;

            do{


             try {
                 wenttocatch=false;
                number_of_rigons=sc.nextInt(); // sc is an object of scanner class 
            } catch (Exception e) {
               count++;
               wenttocatch=true;
               System.out.println("xx");

            }

            }while(wenttocatch==true && count < 1);
```

Answer Comment:

I think you want to get ints until a user doesn't enter anymore. Depending on your input one way of doing that is this

```
int number_of_rigons;
while((number_of_rigons = sc.nextInt()) != null){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: well what i want is i want to get an integer until he enters an integer the while loop should run again and again

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. You want to get all the integers a user inputs until they don't input anymore integers?

Answer (score 0):

you simply can use the hasNext(); method in java, instead of try and catch.
The hasNext() is a method of Java Scanner class that returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] stringArray = new String[lines];
   int i = 0;
   try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
       while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
           String data=sc.nextLine();
           stringArray[i] = data;

           i++;
       }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
       System.err.println("Error opening file.");
       throw new FileNotFoundException();
   } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
       System.err.println("Error in file record structure");
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

/*added the scanner declaration inside try im  new on programming its worked for me but I don't know if its good practice
*/  :

```
    boolean wenttocatch;
    do 
    {
        try 
        {
           
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
         wenttocoatch = false;
        number_of_rigons = sc.nextInt(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        wenttocatch=true;
        System.out.println("xx");
    }
} while (wenttocatch==true);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
....
try {
  ....
} catch (Exception e) {
  sc.next();
  wenttocatch=true;
  System.out.println("xx");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, glanced at this in new posts review and mistakenly thought "well wenttocatch is still true so it's still going to loop". However this is identical to James Jithin's answer.